# Millisecond timing over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, timing

Let's say I have an ncurses app that updates my terminal window at a sub-second interval (every millisecond, let's say, in a loop).

```
while(true)
  write_some_value_to_terminal();
  sleep_for_1_millisecond();
```

If I'm SSHed into my machine remotely, and I run this program, does that mean that SSH will need to do a round-trip every millisecond to update my (remote) window?

**EDIT** A second question, with practical application for the code I'm writing is, how can I determine the optimal sleep value?  Does it even make sense to aim for sub-second timing?

Comment: Depends on buffering. You can always check with Wireshark (it can't tell you what's being sent, but it can tell you how much and how often)

Comment: how fast does your "remote window" update? Would you notice anything in the regime less than 20 ms? I'd suspect writing bunches every say 10 to 20 ms would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Almost. The writing takes some time, after that it will sleep for a ms, then write again.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) it is quite likely that you won't see your updates at 1ms intervals at all.  Not to mention your latency will quite likely be higher than 1ms (unless you are on the same local network) in which case updates will get coalesced by regular TCP ACKing behavior.

Comment: SSH and telnet usually disable Nagle (assuming output is going to a tty; pipes may act differently)

Comment: Please see my updated question.  How can I figure out an approximate sleep value without resorting trial-and-error, assuming--as Ben Voight asserted--that Nagle is disabled?